# Проект Django ошибка пути

Tags: python, django

### Чистая версия кода без изменений

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
```

### Версия кода после моих изменений

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #Auth
    path('signup/', views.signupuser, name='signupuser')
    #Todos
```

Ошибка появилась при добавлении `if` в функцию `def signupuser в файл` :

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth import login

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        if request.POST.get['password1'] == request.POST.get['password2']:
            try:
                user= User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Password did not match'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Password did not match'})
```

**settings.py**

В этом файле изменения только: todo добавил в `INSTALLED_APPS`

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-fjaa8d=4^4fn^=&ed(=3+l1_*)vzmu&(a+)omp9o6u)1(+)dff'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'todo',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'todowo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'todowo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда файл **views.py** имеет такой вид ошибки нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `if request.POST == ['password1'] == request.POST.get('password2')` что-то тут с уловием не то , может вам надо что-то вроде `if request.POST.get(password1']) == request.POST.get('password2')`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Спасибо, но ошибку это не исправило

Comment: пожалста опишите что было до ваших изменений, что стало после ваших изменений, изменения выделите там при помощи маны

Comment: @ganz Здравствуйте, я отредактировал свой вопрос и добавил скрин на котором views.py без использования оператора if , как только я его прописываю у меня появляется ошибка в urls.py как на скрине выше

Comment: @Chester-stt интересует иное,- состояние кода до ваших изменений

Comment: @ganz Занимаюсь по уроку, изменения производил только в этих файлах, проект создал через терминал: django-admin startproject todowo

Comment: @ganz потом добавил приложение python manage.py startapp todo

Comment: @ganz я не делюсь с вами биографией, да, мне нужна помощь по этому я максимально подробно её попытался описать, если бы я понял что вам нужно, то я бы с радостью вам это предоставил. Вы у меня спросили что было до моих изменений - не было ошибки, после моих изменений - появилась ошибка которую я приложил в виде скрина. Все это я описал наглядно в вопросе.

Comment: @Chester-stt мне нужно две версии кода,- первая до ваших изменений, вторая после ваших изменений............. нужно было....... отвечу только завтра

Comment: @ganz "*при помощи маны*" это как?

Comment: Когда делаете login() ничего не возвращаете. Функция должна как минимум вернуть HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

В файле **settings.py** в `TEMPLATES` в `DIRS` указали ли вы путь? -
`'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`

Comment: Весь интернет обошёл, указывал, но это ничего не меняет, при создании приложения все миграции сделал.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос